# How to scale a path in SVG at the same origin?

Tags: css, svg

I would like to create an animation on a path in a SVG. It scales back and forth at the same origin. The problem is my current solution works on Chrome but not on Firefox.

```
.svg-map-pg-logo {
  animation-name: star;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes star {
    0%   {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
      transform-origin: center center;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
      transform-origin: center center;
    }
}
```

On firefox, the path scales while moving to a direction. On Chrome it just scales at its original origin. How to make the scale not moving?

This is what happens on Firefox:
[image]

This is what happens on Chrome and what I want:
[image]

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/jaaPwW

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale seems like Firefox is running by its rules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want transform-box: fill-box;

```
.svg-map-pg-logo {
  animation-name: star;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

@keyframes star {
    0%   {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    }
}
```

Chrome incorrectly defaults to this when the transform-origin is set to center.